# Force Update application by using custom api in flutter

Tags: json, api, flutter

I am getting sick of thinking about how to make application force update by controlling the json api. I want to call json api from my server and want to make your if the app is need to update and show the message box and navigate to this update application. Please share me a sample if you know how to do it in flutter. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my previous jobs, I was asked to add a force update function to the app. I personally don't like it when apps force update you (except when you are in a really old-old version).

This is how I did it (i am not going to paste the code, I am going to simply explain it) when the app started up we had a function that checked an API for the latest version of the app (that app worked only with internet access). If the API returned a newer version we simply displayed a msg informing the user that there is a newer version. If the API had the forceupdate value, I was displaying a msg and disabling everything. The user couldn't perform anything in the app until he updated it to the latest version.